# Multithreading in libevent

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, libevent

I have one thread (Thread A) in a C static library that's creating the libevent `event_base` after doing this:

```
#ifdef WIN32
    evthread_use_windows_threads();
#else
    evthread_use_pthreads();
#endif
```

This C static library is all single threaded and it's doing all the libevent work itself: adding events, dispatching, main loop, etc, all these being done from Thread A.

Now I have a C++ program that I link with the library above, calling the entrance function into the C library from a `boost::thread` called Thread B.

At some point into my C++ program, I have yet another `boost::thread` called Thread C which will attempt to `event_add` using the C library into Thread A's event loop and then immediately call `event_active`.

What I'd like to see after doing stuff from Thread C is this:

```
calling event_add from Thread C
calling event_active from Thread C
Processing events from Thread A
calling the event's handler from Thread A
```

Possibly we could have `Processing events from Thread A` anywhere else between those lines, but for sure we must have at least 1 such line between `event_active` and `event handler execution`, right?

What I see instead is this:

```
calling event_add from Thread X
calling event_active from Thread X
calling the event's handler from Thread A
```

Thread X is a different ID than Thread C but I guess that's just because of using boost threads in the C++ calling site and pthreads in the C library or something, anyways it doesn't bother me.

I also like the fact that my main purpose here is OK: firing the event from a thread and handling it from another.

But for my own curiosity what I don't understand is why I don't see a line "processing events from Thread A" before the handler callback is called?

Thread ids were gotten with `pthread_self()`, this was tested on Linux, more specifically Ubuntu 18.04.